# Deleting entry in SQL Server 2005 - Conversion failed when converting varchar value to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm manually editing a table in SQL Server 2005 and am trying to delete a single record, but I keep getting the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'D' to data type
>   int

None of the columns, int or otherwise contain the value 'D', so I'm very confused by this. I've checked all the tables in the DB where this entry's Primary Key is a Foreign Key, but nothing there either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are there triggers on the table?

Comment: If you have a n/var/char column and then execute a query *... where mycharcol = 123* then you can get this error. Check the columns in your delete where clause. 'D' would be the first non-int value encountered in your column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like there may be a trigger defined on this table - probably some form of auditing.

(I'd guess an audit trigger, since I'm guessing it's trying to insert a row in another table with a `D` to indicate deletion, but I'm also guessing the table definition has changed and the column is now an `int` column).